# Angular 5 Material mat-sidenav toggle not working

Tags: angular5, toggle, angular-material2, mat-sidenav

I'm trying to get the sidenav to work using the official [open/close example](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#opening-and-closing-a-sidenav).

I'm new to Angular, so I'm not sure how everything is supposed to work, but for other components so far I've been good just grabbing the HTML portion of the examples and modifying CSS.

After some trial and error I've figured out that **mat-sidenav-content** is not the content of the sidenav, but the page/site content.

To experiment and get something working, I've done it this way for now, in my **app.component.html** (will likely later move into a directive/component once I figure that out):

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-wrap" fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened>
  yo
  </mat-sidenav>


<mat-sidenav-content>

<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
     
<app-footer-nav></app-footer-nav>
    </mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-container>
```

The example uses **[(opened)]="opened"** on **mat-sidenav**. This just leaves the nav closed for me, where simply using **open** leaves it open. Either way the toggle is broken. The toggle is here, in **topnav.html**:

```html
<div class="pageFullNav">
  <nav class="docs-navbar">
      
        <a mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>   

... etc />
```

Console is failing on the toggle.

```html
TopNavComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TopNavComponent.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at eval (core.js:10629)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
```

I believe this may have something to do with missing Material modules, but as far as I can tell I have all the relevant ones.

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatMenuModule, MatSidenavModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatExpansionModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material';

// add only required modules


@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatMenuModule, MatSidenavModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatExpansionModule, MatRippleModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule, MatMenuModule, MatSidenavModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatExpansionModule, MatRippleModule]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule { }
```

I'd appreciate if any help were very explicit about which files/sections to modify, because this environment is relatively new to me. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're declaring the template variable `sidenav` in app.component.html and then trying to use it in topnav.html. This won't work, as template variables are scoped to the template that declares them, so when looking for `sidenav` in your component and upon not finding anything, it throws that error.

Comment: You're exactly right, thank you. I figured there might be a scope issue but didn't know how the files got served together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by [p4r1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1684458/p4r1) above. Thanks again.

Solution was moving the toggle control into the same file as **side-nav**.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-wrap" fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened>
  <h3>navigate</h3>
  </mat-sidenav>


<mat-sidenav-content>
    <a mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Comment: But I am getting the problem. I am calling sidenav.toggle() from another component by using EventEmitter. Reffered this code [Angular Material: toolbar and sidenav](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/11/10/angular-material-toolbar-and-sidenav/) . This worked with that tutorial but not working in my code. to make things clear. I have made changes in Three files **1 '.ts'  where event Emitter object is created. **2. associated html file for 'Header bar html'.**  **3. Nav page where my navigation menu, router template and this header bar is called with event editor object I have created.**